# Callback function for ClickAwayListener stop midway on execution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, react-router, material-ui

I am using Material-UI `ClickAwayListener` and `react-router` for my app. The bug I encountered is that when the callback for `ClickAwayListener` get executed, it is stopped mid-way for a `useEffect` to run and after that it resume running. This behavior is not expected from a callback. The callback should be fully executed before the `useEffect` can run. Below are the code I create to demonstrate the problem and [this is the demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/callbackstopmidwaywithuseeffect-pj1hj?file=/example.js:0-237) for the code

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ClickAwayListener from "@material-ui/core/ClickAwayListener";

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useHistory,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <ButtonPage />
          </Route>
          {/*Main focus route here*/ }
          <Route path="/:routeId">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

// Main focus here
function Home() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { routeId } = useParams();

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleClick1 = () => {
    history.push("/route1");
  };
  const handleClick2 = () => {
    history.push("/route2");
  };

  // useEffect run on re-render and re-mount
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Re-render or remount");
  });
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Run on route change from inside useEffect");
  }, [routeId]);

  const handleClickAway = () => {
    console.log("First line in handle click away");
    setCount(count + 1);
    console.log("Second line in handle click away");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick1}>Route 1 </button>
      <button onClick={handleClick2}>Route 2 </button>
      <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClickAway}>
        <div style={{ height: 100, width: 100, backgroundColor: "green" }}>
          Hello here
        </div>
      </ClickAwayListener>
    </div>
  );
}

// Just a component such that home route can navigate
// Not important for question
function ButtonPage() {
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleClick1 = () => {
    history.push("/route1");
  };
  const handleClick2 = () => {
    history.push("/route2");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick1}>Route 1 </button>
      <button onClick={handleClick2}>Route 2 </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In specific, when I click outside the `ClickAwayListener` the `handleClickAway` run normally and the logging message is

```
First line in handle click away
Second line in handle click away
Re-render or remount
```

Until I choose to click on the `button` that navigate to other route. Here thing get weird: `handleClickAway` run the first logging line, then the `useEffect` run and print its logging, then `handleClickAway` resume and print its second line. So if I do so this is the logging

```
First line in handle click away
Re-render or remount
Run on route change from inside useEffect
Second line in handle click away
```

After doing some test on this bug I figured out that the thing that cause this bug is the `setCount` inside the `handleClickAway`. If I remove this line the function `handleClickAway` will run as expected for all cases. My conclusion is that, changing component state, or should I say, perform any actions that cause component to re-render inside `handleClickAway`in combination with route navigation can cause this bug.

This behavior is strange, because as far as I know, there is no way for a normal, non-promise related callback to stop mid-way like this. I guess the `ClickAwayListener` somehow make `handleClickAway` into Promise or something. But even then, there is no reason for it to stop at the `setCount` and let `useEffect` run?
Can someone explain this to me?

**Edit 1**: As @Rex Pan point out in this answer, it looks like the `handleClickAway` has `useEffect` run *inside it*. This is the only conclusion I can make from reading the trace stack. But this behavior only happen when the user click to a link that navigate to different route. Clicking to other area beside that doesn't cause this bug.  Can someone explain me why and how this happen?

**Edit 2**: After reading @Rex Pan answer I did some more investigation. It looks like to me that his answer is correct, but only apply for the `ClickAwayListener` callback. So the code below will produce the same "bug" as above

```
export default function ClickAway() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Test in useEffect");
  });

  const handleClickAway = () => {
    console.log("Count is " + count);
    setCount(count + 1);
    setCount(count + 10);
    console.log("Count is " + count);
  };

  return (
    <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClickAway}>
      <div className={classes.root}>Click away</div>
    </ClickAwayListener>
  );
}
```

However, his explanation won't work in other case, like below code

```
export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Run inside useEffect");
  });

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log("First line");
    setCount(count + 1);
    console.log("Second line");
    setCount(count + 100);
    console.log("Third line");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>Count is: {count} </div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

I am trying to read on the source code of `ClickAwayListner` but so far haven't find the location that cause this behavior. Can someone point this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setCount()` cause a render which will flush the `useEffect()` from previous render. This causing the `useEffect()`s is called before `setCount()` return to `handleClickAway()`.

```js
handleClickAway()
    console.log("First line in handle click away");
    setCount(count + 1);
        ...
            effect0000000()
                console.log("Re-render or remount");
            effect_on_routeId()
                console.log("Run on route change");
    console.log("Second line in handle click away");
```

You could verify by add the function name and `new Error()` and check the callstack.

```js
useEffect(function effect0000000() {
    console.log(new Error())
    console.log("Re-render or remount");
  });

  useEffect(function effect_on_routeId() {
    console.log(new Error())
    console.log("Run on route change");
  }, [routeId]);

  const handleClickAway = function handleClickAway() {
    console.log("First line in handle click away");
    setCount(count + 1);
    console.log("Second line in handle click away");
  };
```

[image]

If you click outside,

1. the `handleClickAway()` is called, log `First line in handle click away`
2. the `setCount()` is called and React will re-render `2` which will schedule the `useEffect()` bind to `2`
3. `Home()` returned, `setCount()` returned
4. `handleClickAway()` log `Second line in handle click away`
5. `useEffect()` bind to `2` is called as scheduled

[image]

When route button is click

1. `history.push()` cause a render `2`, which will schedule `useEffect()` bind to `this = 2`
2. `handleClickAway()` called and log `First line in handle click away`
3. the `setCount()` is called
4. React need to flush (called) the previous effect (which bind to `this = 2`) before next render
5. React call `Home()` for render `3` which will schedule the `useEffect()` bind to `3`
6. `Home()` returned, `setCount()` returned
7. `handleClickAway()` log `Second line in handle click away`
8. `useEffect()` bind to `3` is called as scheduled

[image]

Comment: But if that is the case, then why the logging in `handleClickAway` get printed first? And even weirder when its execution stop half-way for the logging of `useEffect` to be printed, then resume (?) running?

Comment: Also I don't think that error stack trace mean that `useEffect` run before `handleClickAway`. As [this article](https://lucasfcosta.com/2017/02/17/JavaScript-Errors-and-Stack-Traces.html) pointed out, that message likely mean that `handleClickAway` somehow call `useEffect` inside itself.

Comment: It's also worth to point out that, if you remove the `setCount` in `handleClickAway`, you will see that the `handleClickAway` no longer in the stack trace. The only conclusion I get is that, by calling `setCount`, `handleClickAway` somehow run the `useEffect` inside itself.

Comment: Yup, that what I said since the beginning. The setState is calling the useEffect()s before it return to handleClickAway().

Comment: I don't think this is the case. Try to click other part but the button you will see that the order of log is different. If what you said is correct then the order should be the same.

Comment: I updated the answer for explaining when useEffect is flushed.

Comment: The order of execution you describe above is correct ([this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-hc0lp?file=/demo.tsx)), but only for the `ClickAwayListener` callback. For normal function it won't work(see [this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-sky-3hmvr?file=/src/App.js)]

Comment: That is because the handleClickAway is run after render 2 (by history.push() by onClick). If handleClickAway is triggered by onBlur (for example), it will run before the render 2 as same with history.push() from onClick().

Answer (score 0):

Here's why this is happening. The `useEffect` uses routeId as one of its props. You're likely navigating when the handleClickAway fires, so the useEffect is triggered and then logs to your console.

Also, are you sure it is *stopping* the execution, and not just logging in between asynchronously? Generally useEffects do not block the execution of any other piece of code.

A simple way to test this would be by delaying the logging in the useEffect. If it is not blocking the execution, your other logs should show first and then this one shows later.

```
useEffect(() => {
   setTimeout(() => console.log('delayed log'), 3000)
}, [routeId])
```

---

Answering your comment:

According to [this](https://medium.com/swlh/what-does-it-mean-by-javascript-is-single-threaded-language-f4130645d8a9) article, any asynchronous call is done outside the call stack, so it won't actually block the execution of your code.

> In a nutshell, the asynchronous implementation in Javascript is done
> through a call stack, call back queue and Web API and event loop.

React is likely doing the same with useEffect, so it doesn't mean that it stopped the execution of your callback to run the useEffect, just that it ran it alongside it.

In the article itself he uses a timeout example like I did here and then explains how it is handled in the stack:

> In Javascript, All instructions are put on a call stack. When the
> stack arrives at setTimeout, the engine sees it as a Web API
> instruction and pops it out and sends it to Web API. Once the Web API
> is done with the execution, it will arrive at the call back queue.

Comment: I edit my code and as you can see, if I don't click on the button, the other `useEffect` still work normally. Also in your point, why does `useEffect` log the message when the callback is already running? The JS main stack suppose to have only one thing running at a time.

Comment: I replied to your comment in the post itself :)

Comment: Both `handleClickAway` and `useEffect` is some form of callback run so it's true that it won't block the code execution. But those callback don't run on call stack - they just wait there and only get pushed onto main stack and execute when there is nothing in the main stack. Once they are in main stack and executing, there is no reason for that callback to stop and let other callback to run, because this callback now has block the main stack. The article you mention doesn't seem to cover all aspect. Watch [this JSConf video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0&ab_channel=JSConf)

Answer (score 0):

when you click on a route button, two events are fired simultaneously and there is a race condition between history.push() and setcount() inside of the two handlers and therefore two independent rerenders are happening and each rerender fires an effect. so its not a bug and two handler functions are doing their jobs at the same time and each of those functions executes all the codes inside of it.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. JavaScript is a single-thread language so race condition is really not a thing. When one function is running in the main stack, no other function can "race" with it.

Comment: you're right but when it comes to asynchronous tasks like react state and effects, the order of execution stack may not be as expected. @rex-pan did a good job tracking the order of execution. looks like all code inside the handleClickAway function is not blocking other functions executions. the term "race condition" is commonly used in such cases